# Should we have a "vote-to-burninate" button

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-deletion

Often here on Meta the demand to burninate a specific tag arises. If the community agrees a moderator burninates the tag.

Should we have a button on the tags page to vote for burnination? 
Or maybe somewhere on the review page?

It could be visible for 2k+ users for instance.

Comment: Why? What is wrong with the current procedure?

Comment: Chances are we'd still need to have meta requests for burnination anyway; a lot of the tags that need burnination aren't viewed enough to get the required exposure.

Comment: Hrm... Nah. Nope.

Comment: Another way to put it is: "5 people don't like C++. They vote to burninate, and the entire tag is gone." So in order for this to work at all, there must be some sort of weighted ratio to prevent abuse. At that point it's more complicated than just making a meta post.

Comment: I like this suggestion. We could finally get rid of php once and for all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discussion around the burnination of tags is extremely important. What you're suggesting would presumably be like the vote-to-close button, where after some threshold of votes is crossed the tag is automatically burned. This absolutely should not happen.

For a tag to go away somebody should definitely be required to post to Meta indicating *why* they think the tag should go away. The community votes on that post and posts counter-arguments. As often as not, the tag doesn't wind up getting burned. The feedback and discussion has to happen.